# How to programmaticaly change the path of a msaccess linked table

Tags: c#, ms-access

I´m looking for a solution to do so using c#.

I have 2 msaccess db and I copy them to user´s machine at the firt execution of the system. Between these dbs I have a linked table which I need to change the path to the user folder.

I´ve looked around but I couldn´t find anything.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try Google and "how to relink access table using c#" (without the quotes) there are MANY answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem some time ago while using VBA, which is probably easier to interface with Access than using C#.

However, after trying out several unreliable options I ended up just dropping the link and creating it from scratch. I would first retrieve all options used by the linked table, replace the database location and create a new linked table with those options, imitatng the old link.

After a quick search I found [ADO.NET way for creating a linked table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461414/ado-net-way-for-creating-a-linked-table) and [How can I link an external Access table via .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573480/how-can-i-link-an-external-access-table-via-net) that should help you with doing that in C#.

Comment: As soon as I try it I will set as answer or not! Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly!